# How to properly structure localized content in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm thinking about migrating to Cloud Firestore from realtime ratabase and wondering how I can properly setup the datastructure for my localized content.

This is how it was structured in RTDB:

```
articles
   en-US
      article_01
   de-DE
      article_01
```

In Firestore, would I create something like this?

```
Collection: articles
   document: article_01
```

And then nest all the data of `article_01` in two maps called 'en-US' and 'de-DE'?

Not sure if there's not a better way to structure localized data in Firestore?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way for structuring such data in Cloud Firestore. So a possible schema might be:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- articles (collection)
        |
        --- articleId (document)
        |     |
        |     --- language: "en-US"
        |     |
        |     --- //other article properties
        |
        --- articleId (document)
              |
              --- language: "de-DE"
              |
              --- //other article properties
```

Using this database schema, in Android, you can simply:

- Get all articles regardless of the language using just a `CollectionReference`:

  ```
  FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
  CollectionReference articlesRef = rootRef.collection("articles");
  articlesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
  ```
- Get all articles that correpond to a single language using a `Query`:

  ```
  FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
  Query query = rootRef.collection("articles").whereEqualTo("language", "en-US");
  query.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
  ```

Comment: Awesome, thank you Alex!

That means that I add all articles regardless of their language in the same collection and then query only for those with the property-language I need, right?

Comment: @phk Yes, that's corect.

Comment: With this solution, how do you know that both are the same article with just different language?

Comment: Nowadays we can use Firestore arrays for that.

Comment: Can you please update your example to the version with arrays? Thanks

Comment: @desmeit Please ask a new question, so I or other Firebase developers can help you.